# workBook.write(fileoutputstream); writes empty excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, fileoutputstream

I am trying to write a excel workbook to a file. Using Apache POI. I debug and found out my workbook have data . Once i write this workbook to FileOutputStream, it successfully writes without any errors. but the generated file have nothing in it. that's a blank file. This is my code for writing the file  :

```
    public void generateOutputSheet(String outputPath)
{
    try
    {
HSSFWorkbook outputWrkBook =     mapBuilder.BuildOutputWorkBook(); // this have two sheets and each sheet have data
                                                                   //( one has 800 rows and another  6000 rows , i verified
FileOutputStream outputFilestream = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);

outputWrkBook.write(outputFilestream);
outputFilestream.flush();
outputFilestream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("the output file is available at location:"+outputPath);

}
```

Comment: How have you checked the number of rows?
Just to be sure .. can you add the following in your example:
`HSSFSheet sheet = outputWrkBook.getSheetAt(0);`
`System.out.println(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()+" "+sheet.getFirstRowNum()+" "+sheet.getLastRowNum());`
... hopefully these rows aren't empty, i.e. contain empty cells ...

Comment: Can you post the BuildOutputWorkBook method?

Comment: It seems that you are re-creating the cells/rows which overwrites the previously created cells with values/

Comment: @kiwiwings : good catch, cells inside the row are empty. made a row copy function to copy all cells of the row and it worked. :)
thanks a lot. :)
thanks MichaelArdan, good hints, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells inside the row are empty. made a row copy function to copy all cells of the row and it worked. :) thanks a lot. :) thanks MichaelArdan, good hints, solved my problem